# Bluetooth to connect with arduino to read and write characteristics

Tags: python, bluetooth, kivy, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm creating an app to connect with an arduino nano 33 iot. The app is up and running, but I need to write a while loop in the background that reads the characteristics value, and based on that value it changes the color in canvas. Since I'm writing the app with kivy, with a while loop in kivy the program won't run.

How could I write the while loop, and have it on the background?

Comment: What api are you using to access BLE in your kivy app? A better approach would be to enable notifications on your arduino characteristic and listen to the changes. That way you wouldn't need a loop